# Difference between GWR in GTWR addin and GWR tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geographically-weighted-regression

I implemented geographically-weighted-regression (GWR) by GWR tool in ArcGIS and bandwidth result is 20307 and next again implement GWR by GTWR addin in ArcGIS and bandwidth result is 0.188 what is difference between them?

Comment: Well, if your data is in a geographic projection one is likely returning a meter or kilometer unit bandwidth while the other is returning the true decimal degree units.

Comment: thanks for your comment how can i find out my unit in GTWR addin

Comment: i changed my coordinates to wgs84 zone 18 N projected coordinate system but nothing is changed